# Does arcgis or dojo provide any feature like OpenLayers.Control.Button?

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-server

I have experienced in openlayers and find that openlayers allow me to overlay the panel with some buttons on map. I can easily define the type of button whether is  OpenLayers.Control.TYPE_BUTTON or OpenLayers.Control.TYPE_TOOL, setting its eventListener and etc.

However, does ArcGIS javascript API or dojo provide the same plug-in? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML:

```
<button id="buttonid" title="ButtonLabelHere" label="TooltipHere"  dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
</button>
```

Position it with CSS:

```
.dijitButton {
    position:absolute; 
    right:20px; 
    top:60px; 
    z-index:99;
}
```

(The `.dijitButton` class is added by Dojo at runtime - if you have more than one button you will obviously want to use a more unique method of identifying each one) and then hook it as you would any other button/link/clickable thing, with [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/on.html) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Hi Juffy, thanks for your reply! I have also got this idea, however I have to rewrite all the activate and deactivate function myself if using this solution because the eventListener will help me automatically trigger deactivate function if the other button is clicked. Perhaps this is my solution if there is no other way.

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do with the buttons - the ArcGIS API does supply some functionality (eg. editing, drawing, printing) pre-built as dijits (and you can probably find some more in the dojox libraries), but if you're just trying to add an arbitrary button to the page to do...stuff...then yes - you're probably going to have to rewrite your event handlers. :(